# SSRS Lookup combined with SUM IIF

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, sum, lookup

I have the following situation (in SQL Server 2008 R2):

[image]

```
. Two datasets (Dataset 1 / Dataset 2) 
. Rows (A - H ) <br>
. Columns (2011 - 2012 - 2013 - P12 M)
```

I recieve the first three columns from dataset 1, the last column (Past 12 Months) with an `lookup` 
on

```
Column A=Lookup(Fields!A.Value, Fields!A.Value, Fields!Total.Value, "Dataset 2")
```

So far so good..

The challenging part:

```
Row B/A = ROW B divided by ROW A
```

I use this statement:

```
=SUM(IIF( Fields!A.Value = "B", Fields!Total.Value, 0)) / SUM(IIF( Fields!A.Value = "A", Fields!Total.Value, 0))
```

But how to get there with an lookup?
How to get to the first question mark (Answer: 2,23)?

I tried to combine the statement with an `lookup`, so far no result. 
Searched the internet and found/tried some URL: 
[SSRS nested iif expression in lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993846/ssrs-nested-iif-expression-in-lookup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Handling it the way the report is designed currently.

You would need to **explicitly** give the value in source expression of Lookup.

```
=Lookup("A", Fields!A.Value, Fields!Total.Value, "Dataset 2")
 /Lookup("B", Fields!A.Value, Fields!Total.Value, "Dataset 2")
```

**Method 2:**

I would probably redesign the datasets and combine the dataset 1 and dataset 2. It will help remove doing funky logic in the report. Use new dataset to populate the matrix.

*New Dataset:*

```
SELECT CAST(Year as varchar(10)), A, Total
FROM DataSet1_Table
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'L12M', A, Total
FROM DataSet2_Table
```

Comment: Method 1 did it! Thanks Anup!